# Is there an Excel formula to find/match words in a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to find/look for words in a range of cells.
I have 4 words (DAY0,DAY3,DAY5,DAY9) that need to be in that range of cells. If not, it should state FALSE.
See my example

[Example of cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oE4r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the range and try:

`=IFERROR(AND(MATCH("DAY0",$C$1:$C$4,0)>0,MATCH("DAY3",$C$1:$C$4,0)>0,MATCH("DAY5",$C$1:$C$4,0)>0,MATCH("DAY9",$C$1:$C$4,0)>0),FALSE)`

Comment: I tried, but it gives a formula error.
I'm kinda new to this type of formulas, but changing the range in this one would just changing these parts "$C$1:$C$4", right? Keeping those $?
A range I have is C2:C5 for example, and C7:C10 etc. But it can also be a range of 3 or less cells.

<code>=IFERROR(AND(MATCH("DAY0",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY3",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY5",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY9",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0),FALSE)</code>

Comment: Yes, the part you want to change i `$C$1:$C$4`. `$` make the range fixed. in order to avoid mistakes import the formula on the cell as it is, click on the cell, and click on the formula bar on the top. Then you will realize that that the range `$C$1:$C$4` has colored borders. from the edge resize the border to fix your range.

Comment: The formula you mention in the comments work correctly, if you have a range of 3 you could you use BUT the answer will be always FALSE

Comment: Ok, I found that using a comma "," doesn't work. Maybe because I'm using excel 2013. I had to replace them with ";".
The formula doesn't give an error when I finish editing it. But now the result gives me a different error. It states #name?.
https://imgur.com/dsF8nBY

Comment: Turns out that is because my excel is stupid and doesn't know english. I had to change the formula to dutch language.

Now it gives me TRUE. But, the results are always true, even if i remove or change a word.
Say, i change DAY3 to DAY4 (in the range), the result is still true.

**edit**
Ok, I'm stupid. The formulas weren't calculated automaticly. I turned it on. It works! Except that when one of those words are missing. The formule gives that #name? error again.
Is there a way it states TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: i can not think for anything else. before i post the formula i test it and it's works ok.

Comment: It works fine. I think it showed some errors because I use excel 2013.
I had to put brackets around the word FALSE at the end. Now it stated TRUE and FALSE when something is missing. I changed the words FALSE to a dutch sentence, and that works as well.
But, it there a way to change the TRUE statement to a sentence? For example: "Subject complete"?

Comment: Yes, replace the `True` with the sentence you want. If this answer helps you please vote it to helps other with the same question.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but where is the TRUE in this formula?

Comment: Try: `=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH("DAY0",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY3",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY5",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0,MATCH("DAY9",$C$2:$C$5,0)>0),"Subject complete"),"False")`

Comment: You're the best! That worked.
Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: I have another question. Is it possible to show which DAY is missing with this formula?